# Dynamic Table with select onChange Event not working

Tags: php, select, onchange

I have a table, with 12 lines (rows) and 10 columns, for columns odd lines (rows), I have one div inside of cell, with index in Id NumColum_NumLine, and for pair lines (rows), i have one select element equal for all. like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaKKq.png)

What i need is when i select load image on div above.

```
<table border="solid">

<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>";    
    for ($A = 1; $A <= 10; $A++)
    {
        if ($i % 2 == 0)
        { 
            echo '<td id="data">';
            $songs = file('pkmlist.txt');
            $options = '';
            $num = 1;
            foreach ($songs as $song) {
                $options .= '<option value="'.$num.'" onchange="load_img('.$A.'_'.($i-1).')\">'.$song.'</option>';
                $num++;
            }
            $select = '<select name="songs">'.$options.'</select>';
            echo $select;
            //echo ''.$A.'_'.($i-1).'</td>';
        } 
        else
        {
            echo '<td id="Pkm"> <div id="'.$A.'_'.$i.'">  '.$A.'_'.$i.' </div> </td>';
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}   
?>
</table>
```

OnChange don't work.

Answer (score 0):

There I found some syntax error. try this ...

```
<table border="solid">

<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>";    
    for ($A = 1; $A <= 10; $A++)
    {
        if ($i % 2 == 0)
        { 
            echo '<td id="data">';
            $songs = file('pkmlist.txt');
            $options = '';
            $num = 1;
            foreach ($songs as $song) {
                $options .= '<option value="'.$num.'">'.$song.'</option>';
                $num++;
            }
            $select = '<select name="songs" onchange="load_img('.$A.'_'.($i-1).');" >'.$options.'</select>';
            echo $select;
            //echo ''.$A.'_'.($i-1).'</td>';
        } 
        else
        {
            echo '<td id="Pkm"> <div id="'.$A.'_'.$i.'">  '.$A.'_'.$i.' </div> </td>';
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}   
?>
</table>
```